# Вывесити матрицу с помощью numpy python

Tags: python, numpy

После выполнения умножения дух матриц с помощью numpy python выводится результат [ 7. 10.]
[15. 22.], а нужно чтобы после запятой выводились значения 7.0. Тоесть вместо 7. выводилось 7.0. Программа вывода представлена ниже. Как исправить вывод?

```py
import numpy as np
#np.set_printoptions(precision=2)
a, b = input().split('|')
a = [list(map(float, e.split())) for e in a.split(',')]
b = [list(map(float, e.split())) for e in b.split(',')]
result = np.dot(a,b)
for i in result: 
    print(i)
```

Comment: `np.set_printoptions(formatter={'float': '{: 0.1f}'.format})`  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891790/pretty-print-a-numpy-array-without-scientific-notation-and-with-given-precision

Comment: вывело [7.0 10.0]
[15.0 22.0]. А как сделать, чтобы после 7.0 и 15.0 ставилась запятая?